Refused to execute inline event handler due to Content Security Policy (CSP) in Chrome extension
I’m building a Google Chrome extension that manages bookmarks on the new tab page. Everything works fine except for an issue with the removal of bookmarks from the favorites list. When I click the “delete” option in the dropdown, nothing happens, and I noticed that my console is throwing a Content Security Policy (CSP) error.
I understand that Chrome extensions enforce a strict CSP and disallow inline event handlers, but I’m struggling to find the correct way to resolve this issue. I would like to avoid using unsafe-inline due to security concerns.
Here is the specific error I’m receiving in the console:

Refused to execute inline event handler because it violates the
following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'".
Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce
('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note that hashes
do not apply to event handlers, style attributes, and javascript:
navigations unless the 'unsafe-hashes' keyword is present.

I understand that this happens due to the use of inline event handlers (like onclick), but I’m not sure how to restructure my code to avoid this problem.
What I’ve tried:

I attempted to modify my manifest.json to allow inline scripts by adding unsafe-inline, but I want to avoid this due to security risks.

I tried using external JavaScript (script.js) to handle events via addEventListener(), but something seems to be missing or incorrectly set up.
{
 "manifest_version": 3,
 "name": "My Bookmarks Manager",
 "version": "1.0",
 "description": "Manage your bookmarks on the new tab page.",
 "permissions": ["bookmarks"],
 "chrome_url_overrides": {
 "newtab": "newtab.html"
 },
 "content_security_policy": {
 "extension_pages": "script-src 'self'; object-src 'self';"
 }
 }


 <div id="favoritesContainer" class="mt-4"></div>

 <!-- Dropdown in card for deletion -->
 <ul class="dropdown-menu">
 <li><a class="dropdown-item text-danger" href="#" id="delete-123">Delete</a>. 
 </li>
 </ul>


 document.getElementById('delete-123').addEventListener('click', function(event) 
 {
 event.preventDefault();
 event.stopPropagation();
 deleteFavorite('123');  // Call the function to delete the bookmark
 });

 function deleteFavorite(url) {
 let favorites = getFavorites();
 favorites = favorites.filter(fav => fav.url !== url);
 localStorage.setItem('favorites', JSON.stringify(favorites));
 renderFavorites(); // Refresh the list
 }



I believe the issue lies with the CSP blocking inline event handlers, and possibly how I’m trying to remove bookmarks. I’m not sure if there’s a better way to add event listeners in my script.js or if I need to restructure my code to comply with the security policy.
How can I solve this issue without using unsafe-inline in my CSP?
Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Show how you load this script in your newtab.html., it should be <script src=foo.js></script>.
